# typescript: Typescript Generic Type definition of 0-n parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism

Typescript Generic Type definition of 0-n parameters

```
interface F<TOut, T1=any, T2=any, T3=any, T4=any, T5=any> {
   (...args: [T1, T2, T3, T4, T5]): TOut
}

let x1: F<string, number, boolean> = (a: number, flag:boolean) => flag? a+"": "-";
let x2: F<number, number | undefined> = (a?: number) => a? a: 3;
let x3: F<boolean> = () => true;
```

But somehow I have to call them this way:

```
x1(1,true, undefined, undefined, undefined);
x2(3, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
x2(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
x3(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
```

How should I change definition of F<...> so I could call them shorter ?, like:

```
x1(1, true);
x2(3);
x2();
x3();
```

Comment: I could redefine with this:

     interface G<TOut, T extends any[]> {
          (...args: T): TOut
     }

     let x1: G<string, [number, boolean]> = (a: number, flag:boolean) => flag? a+"": "-";
     let x2: G<number, [number] | []> = (a?: number) => a? a: 3;
     let x3: G<boolean, []> = () => true;

     x1(1, true);
     x2(3);
     x2();
     x3();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tuple type instead to represent argument types. Tuples can have optional components which will become optional parameters:

```
interface F<TOut, T extends any[]> {
  (...args: T): TOut
}

let x1: F<string, [number, boolean]> = (a: number, flag:boolean) => flag? a+"": "-";
let x2: F<number, [number?]> = (a?: number) => a? a: 3;
let x3: F<boolean, []> = () => true;

x1(1, true);
x2(3);
x2();
x3();
```

**Note** This solution requires 3.0 or higher.

Comment: thanks dude!

and yeah, I was annoyed and wondering how to use optional '?' in generic parameter. Tuples solves that for me!

Comment: NOTE TO ALL:
This only works for typescript 3.1.3

You should all update your ts in order to get this fancy features.

Answer (score 0):

**Still not satisfying answer from myself!**

I could redefine with this:

```
 interface G<TOut, T extends any[]> {
      (...args: T): TOut
 }

 let x1: G<string, [number, boolean]> = (a: number, flag:boolean) => flag? a+"": "-";
 let x2: G<number, [number] | []> = (a?: number) => a? a: 3;
 let x3: G<boolean, []> = () => true;

 x1(1, true);
 x2(3);
 x2();
 x3();
```

But first, I avoid using '[]' brackets

Second, there would be lots of difficulties when implementing this:

```
(a: number, b?: string, c?: string[], d?: boolean) => a;
```

Since I have to define:

```
let x4: G<number, [number, string, string[],boolean] | [number, string, string[]] | [number, string] | [number]> = (a: number, b?: string, c?: string[], d?: boolean) => a;
```

in order to make call:

```
x4(3,"-",[], false);
x4(3,"-",[]);
x4(3,"-");
x4(3)
```